# swift , sort nsmutableArray with objects

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsmutablearray

i have nsmutablearray with objects

> user_id , username , user_Last_Update_Info

and i want to sort this array by user_Last_Update_Info

how to do it ??

Comment: Try using NSPredicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
arrayToSort.sortUsingComparator{
    (obj1:AnyObject!, obj2:AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in
    var dateStr1 = obj1["user_Last_Update_Info"] as NSString
    var date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr1)!
    var dateStr2 = obj2["user_Last_Update_Info"] as NSString
    var date2: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr2)!
    return date2.compare(date1)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help:

```
    // Example for Swift Array
    myArray.sortInPlace {
        obj1 , obj2 in
        dic1.user_Last_Update_Info < dic2.user_Last_Update_Info
    }

// Example for Swift NSMutableArray
// newArr is an optional [AnyObject], you should cast it to what you expect
let newArr = myArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "user_Last_Update_Info", ascending: true)])
```

Comment: this dont work 
nsmtablearraydont have  sortInPlace

Comment: You can cast your `NSMutableArray` in swift array in order to use `sortInPlace`

Comment: @KhaledAld I added example for NSMutableArray.

Comment: i'ts work good thanks